# $X, Y$ metric spaces, $X$ compact, $f: X \to Y$ continuous then $f^{-1}(V) \subset U$

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces, with $X$ compact, and $f: X \to Y$ continuous.
Let $C$ be a closed subset of $Y$.
Show that for any open neighboorhood $U$ of $f^{-1}(C)$ there is an open neighborhood $V$ of $C$ such that
$$
f^{-1}(V) \subset U.
$$

This question is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/257384/14108) but I don't understand the answer.
Specifically, I don't see why
$$
U^c \cap f^{-1}(C) = \emptyset,
$$
with $U^c$ the complement of $U$ in $X$.

Here is my attempt.
Since $U$ is open and $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed then the $f^{-1}(C)$ complement of $U$ is closed. Let $U^c$ be this complement.
since $f$ is continuous, then $f(U^c)$ is closed.
Let $V=C\setminus f(U^c)$, then $V$ is open, but I don't see why 
$$
f^{-1}(V) \subset U.
$$

Comment: If $A\supseteq B$, then $A^c\cap B=\varnothing$; draw a Venn diagram if you don’t see it otherwise. Here $A=U$, and $B=f^{-1}[C]$.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘the $f^{-1}(C)$ complement of $U$’?

Comment: $f^{-1}(C)\subset U\Rightarrow f^{-1}(C)\cap U^c=\emptyset$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The question says $U$ is an open neighborhood of $f^{-1}(C)$, so this means $U \subset f^{-1}(C)$, right?. - By the $f^{-1}(C)$ complement of $U$, I mean $\left[ f^{-1}(C) \setminus U \right] \cap f^{-1}(C)$.

Comment: No, it means that $U\supseteq f^{-1}[C]$ (and $U$ is open).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, notation q: $f^{-1}[C] = f^{-1}(C)$?

Comment: @alancalvitti: I am one of those who make a careful distinction between $f^{-1}[C]=\{x\in X:f(x)\in C\}$ and $f^{-1}(C)$, the latter making sense only when $f$ is an injection from some set with $C$ in its range.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, in other words you distinguish inverse image from image under the inverse map and the latter doesn't necessarily exist here. But since there's no injectivity assumption the OP  and commentators mean $f^{-1}[C] = f^{-1}(C)$ default? - Is there a risk of notational confusion in using $f^{-1}(C)$ here?

Comment: @alancalvitti: In most contexts, including the present one, there’s no real risk of confusion and hence no harm in writing $f^{-1}(C)$ for my $f^{-1}[C]$, and you’ll see the former more often than the latter. I just prefer to maintain the distinction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $U^{c}$ is closed, and hence, compact in $X$. Thus, $f(U^{c})$ is compact, and hence, closed in $Y$ since $f$ is continuous and $Y$ is a metric space.

Let $V=Y\setminus f(U^{c})$. Then, $V$ is an open set. We'll show that $f^{-1}(V)\subset U$. Pick $x\in f^{-1}(V)$. Then, $y:=f(x)\in V$, so that $y\notin f(U^{c})$. Therefore, $x\notin U^{c}$, which means that $x\in U$. Hence, $f^{-1}(V)\subset U$, as desired.